# Нужно выбрать все заявки(orders) к которым есть хотя бы одна ставка(bids) cakephp 3.0

Tags: sql, orm, cakephp

Есть 2 таблицы таблицы, которые связаны через внешний ключ в соотношении один ко многим. Таблица orders 
[image: Таблица orders]

и таблица bids
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно выбрать все заявки(orders) к которым есть хотя бы одна ставка(bids).

На чистом SQL этот запрос не трудно сделать

```
SELECT
* ,
count(bids.order_id) AS count_bid

FROM orders

LEFT JOIN bids
ON bids.order_id = orders.id

GROUP BY orders.id
HAVING (count_bid > 0)
```

Но нужно сделать используя конструктор запросов cakephp 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю на сколько это правильно, но мне удалось выбрать так статью, где есть хотя бы один коммент

```
$query = $this->Articles->find();
$query
  ->select(['count_bid' => $query->func()->count('Comments.id')])
  ->leftJoinWith('Comments')
  ->group(['Articles.id'])
  ->having(['count_bid >' => 0])
  ->enableAutoFields(true);
$results = $query->toArray();
```